# iPad simulators are not displaying in landscape when set to landscape only

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, simulator

'Landscape left/right' are ticked and so is 'Requires Full Screen'. 
'Portrait mode' is unticked.
'Devices' is set to universal. 
The iPhone simulators are correctly displaying as landscape mode. 
The iPad simulators are incorrectly displaying as portrait mode.

Can't work it out :/
Any advise?

Comment: it's not support in iPad because it treat as iphone4 in ipad

Comment: @Sagar bhut  I dont understand??? What do you mean

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found the answer.. Thanks to @Sagar Bhut ..but I havn't a clue what he's on about.

[Look where it says 'supported interface orientations iPad'  you'll see 4 items... I deleted the two 'Portrait' options. Now it works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnlEL.png)

[image: ..I deleted the two 'Portrait' options. Now it works fine.]

Not sure why we have these options but its likely that they are useful in some way.

Thanks and hope this helps someone  :)